# flash drag & drop target not disappear at next frame and scene

Tags: flash, drag, scene

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.media.Sound;

var objectoriginalX:Number;
var objectoriginalY:Number;
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("applause_3.mp3");
var applause:Sound = new Sound();
applause.load(request);
var request3:URLRequest = new URLRequest("laugh.mp3");
var laugh:Sound = new Sound();
laugh.load(request3);

ayat1.buttonMode = true;
ayat1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
ayat1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
ayat2.buttonMode = true;
ayat2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
ayat2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);    
ayat3.buttonMode = true;
ayat3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
ayat3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);    
ayat4.buttonMode = true;
ayat4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
ayat4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);

function pickupObject(event:MouseEvent):void {
    event.target.startDrag();
    event.target.parent.addChild(event.target);
    SoundMixer.stopAll();
    objectoriginalX = event.target.x;
    objectoriginalY = event.target.y;
}

function dropObject(event:MouseEvent):void {
    event.target.stopDrag();
    var matchingTargetName:String = "target" + event.target.name;
    var matchingTarget:DisplayObject = getChildByName(matchingTargetName);
    if(event.target.dropTarget != null && event.target.dropTarget.parent == matchingTarget) {
        event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, pickupObject);
        event.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropObject);
        event.target.buttonMode = false;
        event.target.x = matchingTarget.x;
        event.target.y = matchingTarget.y;
        applause.play();
    } else {
        event.target.x = objectoriginalX;
        event.target.y = objectoriginalY;
        laugh.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question exactly cos I just see a title followed by code dump? What for and where are we looking in this code? Anyways if you want a displayObject (Sprite, MovieClip etc) made invisible then just use `myObject.visible = false;`

Answer (score 0):

Objects won't disappear in the next frame by default.  Only objects placed on a keyframe within the timeline will disappear, and that's only if they're in the same layer as a keyframe without that instance in it.  Scenes are a user abstraction.  As far as Flash is concerned, scene two picks up at the last frame of the previous scene +1.